# How to set string to current date time?

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

I'm working through my first circleci build using [aws-ecr orb](https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/circleci/aws-ecr) and I want my tag to be set dynamically based on the current timestamp. How can I do that?

```
orbs:
  aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@6.2.0
version: 2.1
workflows:
  # Build and push to ECR on builds to master
  build_and_push_image:
    jobs:
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
          account-url: AWS_ACCOUNT_URL
          aws-access-key-id: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          aws-secret-access-key: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          region: AWS_REGION
          repo: node
          tag: <HOW TO SET TAG TO CURRENT DATETIME????>
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

Comment: Is something such as `tag: "some_stuff_$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M')_and_stuff"` which should output something like `some_stuff_2019-12-31_12-25_and_stuff` I had a similar issue and use [this tuto](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/) for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append the date using Linux formatting (date +FORMAT).

As user Al-un mentioned above, [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/) is a great reference on how to use those formats.

Here is [another user](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/how-do-i-inject-project-environment-variable-into-run-cmd/26689/2) who does something similar.

Comment: Both of those examples show how to fill a date in a shell command. The OP's question is about a CircleCI configuration setting, which is not a shell script